# select case when select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need your help in solving this query. i want to fetch choiceName based on some conditions.

Below is code snippet

```
SELECT PSC.SKU_ID, PSC.Choice_ID, PSC.Option_ID, PO.*,
        (
            Case
                WHEN PO.Std_id = 0
                    THEN
                        (SELECT *
                            FROM ProdOpt_choices
                            WHERE option_id = PSC.Option_ID
                            AND choice_id = PSC.Choice_ID)
                WHEN PO.Std_id = 1
                    THEN
                        (SELECT *
                            FROM StdOpt_choices
                            WHERE option_id = PSC.Option_ID
                            AND choice_id = PSC.Choice_ID)             
                            ) AS Choicename
        FROM Prod_SKU_Combos PSC 
        LEFT JOIN Product_Options PO ON PO.Option_ID = PSC.Option_ID
        WHERE PSC.SKU_id = #SKU_ID#
```

any help appreciated.. TIA

Comment: so what's the question or issues you are having? You are missing an `END` to your `CASE`

Comment: You cannot have more than one field in the nested query...

Comment: good catch @Eli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need one column (e.g. `choicename`), and the joins are 1:(0-1) then you can use `left join` for each, and a `case` expression:

```
select psc.sku_id, psc.Choice_id, psc.Option_id, po.*
  , choicename = case 
      when po.Std_id = 0 then poc.ChoiceName 
      when po.Std_id = 1 then soc.ChoiceName 
      else soc.ChoiceName 
      end
from Prod_sku_Combos psc 
    left join Product_Options po 
      on po.Option_id = psc.Option_id
    left join ProdOpt_choices poc
      on poc.option_id = psc.Option_id
     and poc.choice_id = psc.Choice_id
    left join StdOpt_choices soc
      on soc.option_id = psc.Option_id
     and soc.choice_id = psc.Choice_id
where psc.sku_id = #sku_id#
```